# Grant access to multiple individual files in sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have 500 xlsx files in SharePoint site library. Each file belongs to a different specific member in the organization. I can grant Modify permission to each file individually, but maybe there is a command similar to icacls, so I can repeat this command in a loop and grant access to each file very fast?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pnp command to grant user permissions:

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Documents' -Identity 1 -User 'user@contoso.com' -AddRole 'Contribute'
```

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitempermission?view=sharepoint-ps